# Forge model viewer Saving the translated 3D object in our servers or S3 and Matricon SDK integration to digitalize the 3D drawing

Tags: model, integration, opc, forge, viewer

We have 3D models of P&ID (piping and instrumentation diagram) which we are displaying in forge model viewer. We have we queries as listed below

1. when we upload the model as dwg file, the translated 3D model we wish to store on to AWS S3 store and / or our exclusive server. model viewer should subsequently show the translated 3D object in model viewer, where URL is mapped
2. After successful display of the 3D object, we wish to integrate it with OPC Matricon data for system alerts and notifiation.

Appreciate support on the above

we are able to successfuly run viewer, model derivatives and data management api. the translated 3D model could be successfully seen in viewer in a web browser.